# OO alternative to polymorphism in F# when calling F# from C#

Tags: c#, oop, f#

I want to create a library that will create objects using a user-defined function and modify them using another user-defined function.

I have an OCaml background and see a fairly straightforward way to implement it:

```ml
//user side
type userType = { mutable time : float }

let userInitialization () = { time = 0. }    
let userModification t = t.time <- t.time+1.

//my side
let algo initialization modification n =
    let a = Array.init n (fun _ -> initialization ())
    modification a.[0]
    a
```

The problem is that I want that library to be easy to call from C#: having functions as arguments is probably a bad idea.

Interface and abstract class (that would be inherited by `userType`) seems to be the usual OO solution, but I cannot initialize an object if I don't know the (not yet defined) userType making the initialization step, inside my function, impossible.

The only workaround that I can think of is to ask the user for an instance of his `userType` as an argument that would be used to call initialization, but that seems very inelegant.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Make the interface generic?

Comment: If you expect heavy C# usage, you're probably better with an interface, but there's also `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FuncConvert` for converting between C# `Funcs` or `Actions` and F# `FSharpFuncs`.  You could use that on C# side together with your current code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define an interface like this:

```
type IInitAndModify<'T> =
    abstract member CreateNew : unit -> 'T
    abstract member Modify : item : 'T -> unit
```

and perhaps also an object the user can use to pass it to your implementation:

```
type Algo<'T> () =
    member this.Execute (initAndModify : IInitAndModify<'T>, n) =
        algo initAndModify.CreateNew initAndModify.Modify n
```

From C#, it looks like this:

```
public interface IInitAndModify<T>
{
    T CreateNew();
    void Modify(T item);
}

public class Algo<T>
{
    public Algo();

    public T[] Execute(IInitAndModify<T> initAndModify, int n);
}
```

A client developer could use it like this:

```
public class UserType
{
    public float Time { get; set; }
}

public class UserInitAndModify : IInitAndModify<UserType>
{
    public UserType CreateNew()
    {
        return new UserType { Time = 0 };
    }

    public void Modify(UserType item)
    {
        item.Time++;
    }
}
```

and write a program like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new Algo<UserType>();
    var values = a.Execute(new UserInitAndModify(), 10);
    foreach (var v in values)
        Console.WriteLine(v.Time);
}
```

When running the above `Main` method, the output is this:

```
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 5):

I would be inclined to reject the idea that you shouldn't expose functions as arguments in a library exposed to C#, it's becoming pretty common to do so, you need only look at LINQ, TPL, etc.  I don't think too many C# developers would be scared off by that.

I would, however, suggest that you avoid exposing functions with curried arguments to C# as these are not at all convenient to work with.

You can quite easily wrap your algorithm in a function that accepts arguments in tupled form and exposes `System.Func` and `System.Action`s to C#.

```
let csAlgo (initialisationFunc : System.Func<'a>, 
            modificationFunc : System.Action<'a>, 
            n : int) =
    algo (initialisationFunc.Invoke) (modificationFunc.Invoke) n
```

in C# you could then do this:

```
var res = Module.csAlgo(() => new UserType(0), t => t.Time = t.Time + 1, 16);
```

---

As a small aside, you can also use the `CompiledName` attribute to you can get your casing conventions right in each language.  Tag your function

```
[<CompiledName("ExampleFunction")>]
let exampleFunction () = 1
```

Then in C#, it looks like this:

```
var num = Module.ExampleFunction();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have the feeling that a C# developer would rather be feed an object oriented interface but you mark some good point that I will keep in memory.